# Google search: Is it possible to exclude search results that have punctuation between the quoted terms?

Tags: search-engine

In other words, if I search for "beer can", I'll get a number of results that include phrases like "... beer. Can ...". I want to exclude all results that do not contain the term "beer [space] can". I want to remove all possibility of punctuation from the results.

I thought typing "-." or "-'.'" would work, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it helps, but have you tried [[beer can]](https://www.google.de/?q=%5Bbeer%20can%5D)? Possibly with additional exclude phrases such as -"beer cans", -"beercan" etc.?